# Make and Expression available to be used within a Linq to EntityFramework Expression

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, linq, linq-to-entities

I have the following `LINQ Expression` that I need to be able to use within a `LINQ to Entities` query.

There is currently a property like this:

```
[NotMapped]
public Clinic CurrentClinic
{
  get { return AdmissionRoot.CurrentFacility.Compile()(this); }
}
```

Which called the following:

```
public static Expression<Func<Admission, Clinic>> CurrentFacility =
         a => a.Person.PersonLocations.Any(p => p.Clinic.FacilityType != (int)Clinic.FacilityTypes.CommunityServices)
                ? a.Person.PersonLocations.Where(p => p.Clinic.FacilityType != (int)Clinic.FacilityTypes.CommunityServices)
                   .OrderByDescending(l => l.TransferDate)
                   .ThenByDescending(l => l.LocationId)
                   .FirstOrDefault().Clinic
                : a.Clinic;
```

The issue is that I cannot use `CurrentClinic` within a `LINQ to Entities` statement because it will give the following error:

> "The specified type member 'CurrentClinic' is not supported in LINQ to
>   Entities"

I am new to `LINQ to Entities` expressions and was hoping someone would be able to refactor this so it can be used within a `LINQ to Entities` statement something like this:

```
Db.Admissions.Where(
       a => 
            (a.CurrentClinic != null 
              && !a.CurrentClinic.Company.IsHomeCompany 
              && a.ReferralClinicId == clinicid
            ) 
          ||
            (a.CurrentClinic.Company.IsHomeCompany 
              && a.CurrentClinic.ClinicId == clinicid
            )
        );
```

If it can't be done in an `Expression` that I can "add" other criteria onto the end then is there another way/suggestion that would work without compromising speed too much?

Comment: what is `a.CurrentClinic`?, did you mean to use `CurrentFacility(a)`?

Comment: CurrentFacility is just the name given to the original static Expression

Comment: is `CurrentClinic` one of the columns in `Admissions`? or is it a getter which has it's own expression? since from what I can see the error is about accessing `CurrentClinic`, not with `CurrentFacility`.

Comment: The CurrentClinic comes from here:
[NotMapped]
    public Clinic CurrentClinic
    {
      get { return AdmissionRoot.CurrentFacility.Compile()(this); }
    }
Ill edit the question to show this

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is because you're using `CurrentClinic` in your query which is not something that Entity framework can turn into an expression. A possible alternate way to run your query could be

```
Db.Admissions
    .Select(a => new 
    { 
        CurrentClinic = CurrentFacility(a),
        Admission = a
    })
    .Where(a => 
        (a.CurrentClinic != null && !a.CurrentClinic.Company.IsHomeCompany && a.Admission.ReferralClinicId == clinicid) ||
        (a.CurrentClinic.Company.IsHomeCompany && a.CurrentClinic.ClinicId == clinicid));
```

Note: this is untested but should still work.

Comment: Won't the `Db.Admissions.Select` select all admission records from the database?

Comment: Entity Framework should be able to use the `.Where` filter as part of the generated SQL